# libxml2 linking issues

Tags: android, linker, android-ndk, static-libraries, libxml2

I am running an Android project, it had missing libraries that I added, but there is no jar for libxml2, I keep getting this linking error:

Originating from System.loadLibrary("xml2");

07-06 15:46:54.196: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(322): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library xml2 not found
07-06 15:46:54.196: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(322):     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:461)
07-06 15:46:54.196: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(322):     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:557)
07-06 15:46:54.196: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(322):     at com.wiyun.engine.WiEngineDemos.(WiEngineDemos.java:49)

Do i need to add .so to my Android project configuration? How? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to have been an issue with Eclipse... If anyone has the same issue they should simply restart Eclipse, and check that all NDK configurations are properlly set, like name matching, etc...

Answer (score 0):

libxml2 is a C library, not a java library unless you have found a version that has been ported to java. You need to compile it and then use Android's [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) to access it or you need to try and find a java port.

Comment: The library is compiled, it's an .so file similar to a .dll in win, it just wont link for some reason, there must be something wrong with the linker this is from a Chinese company so there are all sort of issues that I solved by using UTF-8, but I am not able to link for some reason... How do you add and link .so files in the apk?

Comment: it sounds to me like you need to use the NDK.

Comment: I am using the NDK. That is not the problem, the problem is in linking the .so files with my project. I am not compiling any native code. Just linking to shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

> 07-06 15:46:54.196: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(322): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Library xml2 not found

It looks to me that your library is simply not found. Are you sure libxml2.so is included in your APK and being copied to /data/data/*your.package.name*/lib/?

For a .so to be included in your APK it generally needs to be under obj/local/armeabi (If you have a jni folder under your project and using the Android.mk / ndk-build system, it will automatically be 'installed' here)